# Change value of DisplayDiscountedPriceIfAny from FALSE to TRUE * powershell .exe.config file xml *

Tags: xml, powershell

Change value of DisplayDiscountedPriceIfAny from **FALSE to TRUE** powershell .exe.config file
A script where I dont want to change the name, just the value from false to true.

```
# this is the part of the file I have to modify:

<setting name="DisplayDiscountedPriceIfAny" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
</setting>

# it should look like this when done:

<setting name="DisplayDiscountedPriceIfAny" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
</setting>

> I tried this but its obviously wrong

# Load the xml document
$filename = "C:\Users\files\HandheldOfflineSynchronization.exe.config"
$xmlDoc = New-Object xml
$xmlDoc.Load($filename)

# Select all applicable nodes
$nodes = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//appSettings/add[@key="key1"]')

# In each node, replace the value `Value1` with `NewValue`
foreach($node in $nodes){
  $node.value = $node.value.Replace('DisplayDiscountedPriceIfAny','False')
}

# Save the document

$xmlDoc.Save($filename)
```

```
<setting name="LogDated" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Language" serializeAs="String">
        <value>cs</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="LogMaxLevel" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Info</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConnectionStringName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Posybe</value>
            </setting>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example you only have to specify '//setting' to select those nodes:

```
$nodes = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//setting')
```

Later in the loop you can assign the new value:

```
$node.value = 'false'
```

Comment: Thank you, but one more question since I havent explained it correctly. I have cca 8 sections named ''setting'' but I want to change value of just name= "DisplayDiscountedPriceIfAny".

Comment: I edited the question, there is a next fart on the bottom

Comment: please add the complete xml